# Powershell, send email with outlook as different email

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

We have some powershell automation in place which sends an email with outlook with one email account but we are looking for a way to be able to set the sender email address to a different outlook account we have access to.

I've tried googling and looking round on here and cant seem to find the way of doing it.

here is the code we are using.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject  Outlook.Application 
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
start-sleep 5
$Mail.subject = ""
$mail.
$Mail.To = ""
$Mail.Cc = ""
$Mail.Body = "Test" 
$Mail.Display()
$Mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below Outlook function to send the email. You are actually doing the same over there. Is there any error you are getting ? Anyways, Use the below one:
Follow all the comments in the function for your reference.

```
Function Global:Send-Email { 
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0)]
[String]$Address = "user2@domain.com",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[String]$Subject = "Mail Subject",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
[String]$Body = "MailBody"
      )
Begin {
Clear-Host
# Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
    }
Process {
# Create an instance Microsoft Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "$Address"
$Mail.Subject = $Subject
$Mail.Body =$Body
# $Mail.HTMLBody = "HTML BODY"
# $File = "D:\CP\timetable.pdf"
# $Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
$Mail.Send()
       } # End of Process section
End {
# Section to prevent error message in Outlook
$Outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
$Outlook = $null
   } # End of End section!
} # End of function

# Example of using this function
Send-Email #-Address User2@domain.com
```

**Note:** If you want to send email from someone's behalf then you have to enable anonymous mail from the connectors or the user should have the permission to send mail from someone's behalf. In that case, you can add one more object as

> $mail.From=""

One **sample example to send mail from GMAIl** as reference.

```
$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "AnotherEmail@YourDomain.com"
$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "Insert body text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $Attachment
```

Hope it helps...